# Symfony2 Get a form via Ajax

Tags: symfony

I call a form with ajax, instead of display it in page.

Everything is working, except 1 strange thing.

When i call the form via ajax and add it to the page, defaults values are not in fields.

But if i call the form via normal url, default value are set...

```
$builder
        ->add('email', null,array('data' => 'default value')
        ->add('type_form', null, array('data' => 'default value', 'property_path'=> false))
        ->add('list_choice', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => $options['list'],
            'expanded'=>true,
            'multiple'=>true,
        ));
```

The field email and type_form do not display the 'default value' as value except if i call the form via his url, and not via ajax.

Is there a specific way to call form via ajax ?
Thanks for your answers.

Here the way i create the form in my controller

```
$this->container->get('templating')->render('MyappSiteBundle:Contributions:filter_themes_form.html.twig', array(
'form'=> $form->createView(),
'type'=> $type ));

$response = new Response(json_encode(array('form'=> $response_form)));


$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return $response;
```

Then i was calling the form...

Comment: How exactly do you call the form with Ajax?

Comment: I use jquery, i call the route of my controller action, it create the form and return it in a Json var. then jquery will do a innerHtml to add the form to the page.

Comment: Please move your solution to the problem from the question to an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I was clearing form data before to send it:

```
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bindRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $data = $form->getData();
            return $data;
        }
    }
```

Then I was calling the form.